# Azure Ubuntu VM: Where is my public key file stored (used for SSH login)

Tags: azure, ssh-keys

With Azure linux virtual machines (Ubuntu in particular), when opting for PKI authentication, where does it store the public key on the server?  I can't find any .pub files in my ~/.ssh directory.  I've googled and almost every article indicates it's a .pub file in the ~/.ssh directory.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SSH PKI, the client side keys are stored in client's `.ssh` directory.

The keys are `id_rsa` for private key and `id_rsa.pub` for public key.

On the server side, one needs to add client public key to `.ssh/authorized_keys`. So, on SSH servers, clients' public keys are in that file.